# ASP.NET root paths

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this exception when trying to save a file:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/Thumbs/TestDoc2//small/ImageExtractStream.bmp' is not rooted.
at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename)
at System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper.SaveAs(String filename)
at PitchPortal.Core.Extensions.ThumbExtensions.SaveSmallThumb(Thumb image) in C:\Users\Bich Vu\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PitchPortal\PitchPortal.Core\Extensions\ThumbExenstions.cs:line 23
```

The code is below:

```
public static void SaveSmallThumb(this  Thumb image)
    {
        var logger = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILoggingService>();

        string savedFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(
          image.SmallThumbFolderPath,
          Path.GetFileName(image.PostedFile.FileName)));
        try
        {
            image.PostedFile.SaveAs(savedFileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Log(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is your path being produce (possibly due to failure of MapPath):

```
~/Thumbs/TestDoc2//small/ImageExtractStream.bmp
```

Notice the 2 `//` between `TestDoc2` and `small`.

You combine seems to be the issue that is probably causing the double slash.

What is the output of `image.SmallThumbFolderPath` and `Path.GetFileName(image.PostedFile.FileName)`?

The `SaveAs` requires a physical path (eg. `c:/Thumbs/TestDoc2//small/ImageExtractStream.bmp`).

Comment: I thought it might be ,let me look at it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MapPath isn't mapping your path properly. You probably have a `/` at the end of smallthumbfolderpath and at the begining of image.postedfile.filename, resulting in the double-slash in your resulting path. Remove the `/` from either one of these and the MapPath call should return properly.

The SaveAs method is expecting a rooted path, which means that it starts with a drive letter. Make sure that your path doesn't start with a `~` after you run MapPath and you should be fine.